# Tkinter: how to change end index to spaces

Tags: python, tkinter

So i making a text editor and im fixing my previous issue by typing `tag_add()` to my code
**CODE**

```
#Importing modules
from tkinter import *

#Main Window
Window = Tk()
Window.geometry("400x550")
Window.minsize(400, 550)


##Main Script
#Defs
def check_syntax(event=None):
    #Tag adds
    #Import syntax
    text.tag_add("import", "1.0", "1.6")

    #Tag configures
    text.tag_configure("import", foreground="yellow")


"""
def check_syntax(event=None):
    offset = '+%dc' % len("import")

    pos_start = text.search("import", 1.0, END)

    pos_end = pos_start + offset

    text.tag_add('import', pos_start, pos_end)
    #text.tag_remove("import", 1.0, END)

def del_for_check_syntax(event=None):
    text.tag_remove("import", 1.0, END)"""

#Main frame
main = Frame(Window)

#Main text widget
text = Text(main, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, bg="#323232", fg="white", font=("Hack Italic", 20), undo=True)

#Menu bar
#Mainmenu
mainmenu = Menu(Window)

#Filemenu
filemenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)

#Commands
#Filemenu commands
filemenu.add_command(label="New")

#Configs
text.config(width=55, height=35)
main.config(width=55, height=35)

#Tag config for coloring syntax
#text.tag_configure("import", foreground="yellow")

#Highlighting syntax
text.bind("<Return>", check_syntax)

#text.search()
Window.update()

#Binds
#text.bind("<Return>", check_syntax)
text.bind("<Key>", lambda: print("Unsaved"))

#Packs and places
#main.place(anchor="c", rely=.5, relx=.5)
main.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side="right")

text.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

#Update window
Window.update()

#Window.mainloop()
Window.mainloop()
```

**PROBLEM**
The tkinter only highlighting the `import` in line 1 and not highlighting the next line

**QUESTION**
Is there any way to make end index to spaces, i mean the end index is on space, so everytime user type `import` in text widget the next line is highlighted too and not just 1 line, and then the start index started in new space with `import` in text widget

**EDIT**
Thanks @AST, it worked but why is other syntax is highlighted too?, i mean other words than "import"

Answer (score 1):

So, by what I understood from your question, I've improvised the code, please check and tell if this is what your requirement was.

```
#Importing modules
from tkinter import *

#Main Window
Window = Tk()
Window.geometry("400x550")
Window.minsize(400, 550)


##Main Script
#Defs
def check_syntax(event=None):
    #Tag adds
    #Import syntax
    current_line = text.index(INSERT).split(".")[0]
    text.tag_add("import", f'{current_line}.0', f'{current_line}.6')

    #Tag configures
    text.tag_configure("import", foreground="yellow")


"""
def check_syntax(event=None):
    offset = '+%dc' % len("import")

    pos_start = text.search("import", 1.0, END)

    pos_end = pos_start + offset

    text.tag_add('import', pos_start, pos_end)
    #text.tag_remove("import", 1.0, END)

def del_for_check_syntax(event=None):
    text.tag_remove("import", 1.0, END)"""

#Main frame
main = Frame(Window)

#Main text widget
text = Text(main, bd=0, highlightthickness=0, borderwidth=0, bg="#323232", fg="white", font=("Hack Italic", 20), undo=True)

#Menu bar
#Mainmenu
mainmenu = Menu(Window)

#Filemenu
filemenu = Menu(mainmenu, tearoff=0)

#Commands
#Filemenu commands
filemenu.add_command(label="New")

#Configs
text.config(width=55, height=35)
main.config(width=55, height=35)

#Tag config for coloring syntax
#text.tag_configure("import", foreground="yellow")

#Highlighting syntax
text.bind("<space>", check_syntax)

#text.search()
Window.update()

#Binds
#text.bind("<Return>", check_syntax)
text.bind("<Key>", lambda out = "Unsaved": print(out))

#Packs and places
#main.place(anchor="c", rely=.5, relx=.5)
main.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH, side="right")

text.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH)

#Update window
Window.update()

#Window.mainloop()
Window.mainloop()
```

Here I have used `text.index(INSERT)` to get the position of the insertion cursor in the text widget. You can refer to this [http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#:~:text=Indexes%20are%20used%20to%20point,line%2Fcolumn%20(%E2%80%9Cline.](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#:%7E:text=Indexes%20are%20used%20to%20point,line%2Fcolumn%20(%E2%80%9Cline.) for more information. Then used `f""` to insert the `current_line` variable into the string, so, now the index is dynamically changed depending on the line you are at.
Also, you used the `lambda` function incorrectly, the syntax is `lambda arguments: expression`.